# Best of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, indexing

I've started a project to list questions with the 'best' answers, like the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/). It's a wiki hosted on Wikia, called [Best of Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.wikia.com/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Wiki).

I'm defining best as:

- At least one very good answer with code included (or explained)
- Answer should cater to users of any level of skill (ie. don't expect a math background)
- The question should cater to a useful topic (not 'I've got error X with platform Y')
- The topic should be important, that even people not specifically looking for it should find it
- The topic should be a popular problem or question, not a fringe use-case

Now before you all jump on me saying "there's no need for such a thing!", let me reason why such a list could be useful. You're a mediocre developer with no specific problem on your mind. You browse through the top voted questions on SO, but you find that it's not categorised in any specific manner (although you can filter, and get somewhere), but eventually you get bored scrolling through lists of varied questions and leave. What if you had a site that listed useful questions by category? Let's say you visited Best of Stack Exchange, the "Stack Overflow" section and clicked on the category "Databases". You would see a long list of categorised database questions and answers that you could easily jump to if you wanted to know about any. This way we're indexing the best of each Stack Exchange site so users of any skill level can leverage the massive knowledge stored deep within the wells of each website. Also, many good questions that have been answered fairly well are not voted highly, and therefore gets mixed up with all the other questions on the sort-by-vote section even if you filter by a tag. And when questions are organized under a well-defined [category structure](http://stackexchange.wikia.com/wiki/Stack_Overflow) you could narrow down to your interests quickly.

What say?

Comment: +1 and *. Seems interesting.

Comment: Seems the last word of the fourth bullet is lost

Comment: @Peter - Contacted the stackoverflow team directly requesting permission to use the words StackExchange in the wiki logo.

Comment: How is that different from a) going to Stack Overflow b) applying a search/filter on your topic of intertest (e.g. "databases") c) sorting the results by number of votes, to see all the 'best' within that topic?

Comment: Because a) even the database-related questions will be sub-categorised, under headers such as "Caching", "Security", "Performance", "Structure", "Architecture", etc, b) non-useful questions and debates/discussions will not be listed (ie, for the top voted "databases" questions, "Twitter image encoding challenge", "What was the strangest coding standard rule that you were forced to follow?" would not feature and c) many good database related questions are voted < 5 and would never feature highly on top-voted pages to be found. Under a categorized index however, you'd be guaranteed to find it.

Comment: Also, d) questions would be grouped by sub-category and not all mixed up in one list, e) questions would be sorted by importance (more important concepts higher), not by "vote" which is highly subjective. Essentially we're trying to index the most useful questions, that anyone in the field could learn something from. Questions that you usually find in an FAQ, had one been built.

Comment: @Jarvis - +1. Just what I was about to type (and then get down voted for). This would be a great feature for learners.